# (Basic Geometry) What is a geometric object that is universally inverse symmetric about a point called?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, terminology, symmetry

I may be explaining this wrong, but hopefully, an example will make things clear. Take a look at this figure where every black line that passes through the blue dot separates the original red traced shape into two "inversely" symmetric sub-traces that each has the same area (and are essentially just flipped images of each other):

[image]

Is there a geometric term to describe shapes like these?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's **centrally symmetric**. (Attested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_reflection)

(In two dimensions, it happens to be the same as $180^{\circ}$ rotational symmetry, but in higher dimensions, these concepts are different.)

Edit: Oh I almost forgot, a stronger notion is a [balanced set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_set). A set is balanced if and only if it is both centrally symmetric and [star convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain) (around the same point). In your example, it looks like the inside of the red curve is balanced.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your reply this is exactly what i needed.

Comment: What would u say is the significance of a balanced set in geometric applications?

Comment: @PythonMan1029 Significance, I'm not sure of generally. I last had reason to know about this stuff ages ago, when I was working on outer billiards. If you apply the outer billiard map twice, that's related to taking the billiard table plus its reflection across a point. The union of the two is centrally symmetric by construction, but it isn't balanced. I think I also cared about balanced sets for some reason around the same time, but I've forgotten why!